# What is a single word for the capability of a theory, for example, to generate further thought and theorizing?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are a few words which I blank on quite frequently. Perhaps my "advanced" age has something to do with it. I don't know. One such word for me is *euphemism*.

There is another word I am blanking on right now. In my answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190334/food-for-thought-in-a-word/190356#190356) I also blanked on the same word.

It is a word which describes the power of a quotation, or memorable words, or a theory to stimulate further thought and perhaps research. The word is similar in meaning to prolific, which can denote having the power to generate many further thoughts and ramifications of the original quotation, words, or theory.

If you would be so kind as to supply this word for me and perhaps give me a mnemonic device to make it accessible to me, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Its furtherability?  expandability?

Comment: Illuminate? Inspirate?

Comment: thought-provoking?

Comment: Oh! You must mean *[legs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+legs)*; if a story has legs, it grows and grows

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Done. To be honest, I post questions so rarely that I'm not terribly familiar with the protocols in place. Don

Answer (score 6):

I would such a stimulating quotation is ***evocative*** (it **evokes** other, latent, concepts), ***suggestive*** (it **suggests** other ideas to you), or ***inspiring*** (it **inspires** you).

If you're trying to emphasize the *productivity* of the word, the sheer amount of other ideas it generates, you might use an agricultural metaphor, such as ***fertile***, ***fruitful***, or ***fecund*** (or, even more indirectly, ***bounteous*** or ***plenteous***, or as a noun, a real ***cornucopia***).

If you want to underscore that a particular work *has already* had a significant impact and influence on later works, you could say it is ***seminal***, or, rarer and less strong, ***germinal***.

And finally, scraping the bottom of the synonymic barrel, we have both ***batful*** ([yes, seriously](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/batful)) and the archaic term [uberous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uberous):

> ***uberous***: fruitful; copious; abundant; plentiful

Which, I guarantee you, is [poised for a comeback](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=uber).

Comment: You beat me to evocative, drat.

Comment: +1 for *Fertility*, *fecundity*, *fruitfulness* (the nouns correspond to the **capability** sought).

Comment: Your answer is a list of adjectives which , though interesting, might be of difficult access  to OP.  The site policy encourages  the use of links and adequate reference to support the content of their answers so that OP and others users can easily have access to the information provided. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: @josh61 OP asked for  a synonym for *prolific*, which is an. adjective, so I correspondingly supplied adjectives. He also asked mnemonics to aid accessibility, and to the extent I could provide those, I did (parenthetical statements, imagery, alliteration, etc). I am familiar with  site policy, no need to remind me of it (particularly when such reminders are hypocritical), thank you.

Comment: @DanBron: You've provided an excellent list, but THE word isn't there. As I've been telling commenters, I'll know it when I see it. Either that, or ten-and-a-half hours from now when I'm drifting off to sleep, it'll come to me. Darn those sometimes unpredictable synapses! Don

Comment: See my answer, below. Don

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest ***thought-provoking***.

> interesting in a way that makes you think of new ideas or that changes your attitude to something [[macmillandictionary]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/thought-provoking)
>
> stimulating interest or thought 
> [[thefreedictionary]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thought-provoking)

---

> *What is most thought-provoking in these thought-provoking times, is that we are still not thinking.* 
> – Martin Heidegger

Comment: Great synonym, ermanen, but not the one I'm looking for. Gosh, this is frustrating. When I see it, I'll put it on a Post-It note and display it prominently. Better yet, I'll ensconce it behind matte board, frame it, and then screw the frame to the wall in my study. Don

Comment: Is it one of the synonyms? http://thesaurus.com/browse/thought-provoking

Comment: No, it's not. Thank you for the link, by the way. The word I'm searching for is the by-product of a paradigm, I guess. A paradigm which has tremendous explanatory power stimulates further meaningful study and research. Guess my synapses are stuck. Do you think electroshock therapy would help? Don

Comment: See my answer, below. Don

Answer (score 2):

You can describe such a theory as *[provocative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provocative)*:

> Causing discussion, thought, argument, etc.

Note the use of *provocative* to describe the theories in these articles:

> *[How to test Weinstein's provocative theory of everything](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn23632-how-to-test-weinsteins-provocative-theory-of-everything.html#.U-z4efldXbM)*
>
> *[Lab Findings Support Provocative Theory On Cancer 'Enemy' Within](http://www.npr.org/blogs/health/2012/08/01/157706171/lab-findings-support-provocative-theory-on-cancer-enemy-within)*

Comment: Thanks! Good synonym, but not THE one I'm looking for. I'll recognize it when I see it, however. Don

Comment: See my answer, below. Don

Answer (score 2):

I think the term OP is looking for is...

> ***reach*** noun 3 b. *- range or scope of influence or effect.* [(thefreedictionary.com)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reach)

I can't find an actual instance offhand in the book I'm currently reading, but I'm quite certain more than once in [David Deutsch's *The Beginning of Infinity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beginning_of_Infinity) he makes the point that a "good" theory is one which has extensive ***reach***. Consider this from [a review of another of his books](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/books/pages/d/DavidDeutsch.htm)...

> One feature he notes in explanations is that some are universal: they have unbounded "reach", much greater than the domain they initially described.

Comment: Good word to remember, but no, it's not the one I'm blocked on. As I've been telling commenters and answerers, I'll know it when I see it. Don

Comment: @rhetorician: Ah well - if you already "know" the word you're looking for (but simply can't call it to mind) I suppose we're all just firing off shots into the dark here. The review page I linked to uses ***reach*** five times with this quite specialised sense (of a *theory/explanation*, that engenders or supports *other* theories). But two of those five are "in quotes", suggesting not everyone is quite so taken with the usage as myself and Deutsch.

Comment: See my answer, below. Don

Answer (score 2):

A [rich theory](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=5G1&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=sb&q=%22a%20rich%20theory%20of%22&oq=%22a%20rich%20theory%20of%22&gs_l=serp.3...7267.11880.0.12380.5.5.0.0.0.0.143.590.0j5.5.0....0...1c.1.51.serp..3.2.249.AaxhAeeppdI) leaves many [bright pebbles on the sea shore](http://up-grade.me/frame/viewonline.htm?onlineId=25i73899l3&term=True%20Knowledge%27%27).

Comment: I like "rich theory," but I think the word I'm after is a single adjective. I was exposed to it initially in grad school when the discussion in a seminar concerned the ability of a really good theory to generate more and more worthwhile research. Don

Comment: @rhetorician, can you remember anything else about the word? What letter it starts with, maybe? Words it rhymes with? An individual who used it in a famous quote? A textbook that definitely contained it? In this age of the internet, any tiny clue is an exponential improvement.

Comment: See my answer, below. Don

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if my answer will reach the good people who proffered their answers to my question, but having come across by accident today the word I was looking for, I must needs lay it on ya'll. The word is

> ***HEURISTIC***

Rest assured I've written the word on a piece of paper and have taped it to the visible side of the filing cabinet next to my desk, where it will remain in perpetuity.

My apologies to those of you answerers who think the word *heuristic* doesn't match the definition I included in my question.

By the way, I'm still open to your suggested mnemonic devices to help cement the word within my cerebral cortex.

Comment: I suppose it's a bit of a cheek to downvote what you obviously "know" is the word you were looking for, but [check this out](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9NzYyd7qxT0C&pg=PA81&dq=%22heuristic+approach%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ofkqVI-ZDtLg7QablYDoDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22heuristic%20approach%22&f=false). Most people wouldn't even understand your usage, because *heuristic* is now so common in the computing "trial and error" sense. But that "derives" from the "unstructured" sense as used in educational contexts anyway. If you don't like *reach*, I think you need something like *productive*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, I believe you are being a bit cheeky, but that's OK. I have relatively thick skin. I "knew" the word I was looking for, but only inchoately. As I said in my question, the word I was searching for had evaporated from my cerebral cortex, and I was semi-desperate in wanting to use the word once again. I believe I learned the word in graduate school way back when, and I still think it's perfectly apt in matching the stuttering definition in my question. I've been known to be wrong, however. Back in '03 (1903), for example, I forgot to say thank you to a friend. Big mistake.

Comment: I only knew the computing usage until I found *Educational: Of or relating to an educational method or resource that enables students or children to learn by making discoveries for themselves, rather than being directed* in OED yesterday. But today I just searched Google Books for *"**a heuristic theory**"* and found [*A **heuristic theory**, in contrast to a **nomological** one, appeals to our knowing how to go about in the world*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22heuristic+theory+in+contrast%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Forcing me to look up...

Comment: **nomological** = [**nomothetic**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nomothetic) *Of or relating to the study or discovery of general scientific laws.* I'd have thought the implication is that *nomological/nomothetic* theories are the ones that lead to ***further*** theories, because they're based on ***general*** principles, not context-specific ones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for the "google books" ploy; never used it before. The nomological way of going about things reminds me of lawyers' (and paralegals') search for precedents (past cases) which support a contention they're about to make in the instant case. The ideal case on point would be a case in which all four elements of the case (parties, circumstances,
legal issues, and remedies sought) are very similar;
such a case is called a case “on all fours.” Also, I seem to think there's a strong connection--a symbiosis, even--between a heuristic idea or theory and a paradigm.

Comment: I just made a meaningless edit to your answer so I could retract my downvote. On reflection I think I'm not really qualified to have an opinion of the merits of ***heuristic*** here (but I resolutely defend ***reach*** as exceptionally relevant).

Comment: [Heuristic](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict2&Database=*&Query=heuristic) seems to match the definition in the OP exactly. Granted, it's used far more often in a slightly different (albeit related) sense, but it fits nevertheless.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for repenting regarding the down-vote thingy. I believe God honors our acts of contrition! (If I could use an interrobang/percontation point/irony mark/Temherte slaqî/rolling-eyes emoticon instead of an exclamation point, I would, but . . ..) Don

Comment: @CarSmack: Have pity on the old man! Wait until you're 64! (That reminds me of the Beatles' song, "Will you still need me, Will you still feed me, When I'm sixty-four?") Only THEN will you really understand. Don

Comment: I've copied Fumble's comments (with attribution) at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/601150/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-how-a-being-decides-what-is-true, because I suggested "heuristic" as an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

[Generative](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Generative) may convey the idea:

> - Adj. 1. generative - having the ability to produce or originate; "generative power"; "generative forces"

Comment: The OP asked for a synonym for *prolific*.

Comment: Thanks! Close, but no cigar. I'll know it when I lay eyes on it. Don

Comment: See my answer, below. Don

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, *profuse* is the word you're looking for:

> (esp. of something offered or discharged) exuberantly plentiful; abundant

Comment: See my answer, below. Don

Answer (score 1):

The **catalytic** theory inspired dozens of researchers.

Einstein's **controversial** theories still prompt new discoveries today.

Comment: I like this a lot! But perhaps, since "catalytic" is usually only used in scientific contexts, and therefore there's a risk that "catalytic theory" would be taken to mean "a theory *on* or *about* catalysts" (that is, a theory *dealing with* catalysts), for the sake of describing a theory which is *itself* a catalyst (that is: stimulating, rich, etc), we'd prefer the wording "***catalysing** theory*"?

Comment: See my answer, below. Don

Answer (score 1):

Sagacious and gnostic are appropriate for most knowledge-based sentiments, though really, this question seems thoroughly answered.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. I appreciate the collegial, concerted collaboration. Don. P.S. Welcome to the site. Feel free to contribute. If you have any questions about the site's modus operandi, you can always go to EL&U Meta.

Comment: I appreciate the welcome and advice. Sidenote: I love your name.

Answer (score 1):

People have been using **Mind-blowing** for Neil deGrasse Tyson’s work on Cosmos "A space time Odyssey"

http://www.thefrisky.com/2014-03-19/16-mind-blowing-quotes-from-cosmos-a-spacetime-odyssey-so-far/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and welcome to Stack Exchange EL&U. Come on in; the water's fine. Don

Answer (score 1):

I think the word **productive** closely matches what you are looking for. Note its uses [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=r8MQgh5cVGgC&pg=PA38&dq=%22productive%20theory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH2N6y9fbMAhVMDlIKHb9aDOEQ6AEIQDAH#v=onepage&q=%22productive%20theory%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=AN8UDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA220&dq=%22productive%20theory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH2N6y9fbMAhVMDlIKHb9aDOEQ6AEITDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22productive%20theory%22&f=false), and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y2WVhYQn9g0C&pg=PT151&dq=%22very%20productive%20theory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0r7f29fbMAhUWU1IKHbmiCcEQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=%22very%20productive%20theory%22&f=false). If you search Google Books for "very productive theory" you can find many more examples.

The term is in wide academic use with this sense (the sense of being generative, broadly applicable, and useful in a variety of cases, and of lending itself to further research).