# Is there a word or phrase for how a being decides what is true?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there any word or phrase that refers to the set of methods that a certain being will use to work out what is true and what isn't true? It should be a noun or noun phrase. The phrase must refer to specifically the methods that are inherently part of the being's reasoning, rather than learned philosophies

Example Sentence: "Humans have a different _______ to most other species due to our adaptations language"

Comment: But how does language detect or analyze what's true or not?

Comment: I would suggest epistemology, but I don't think that clearly separates innate and learned methods.

Comment: What's a being, and what happened to your missing periods?

Comment: The philosophical term you're asking about is _Epistemology_. It studies how humans can tell what's true. It's usually studied along with _Ontology_, which studies what things there are and tries to distinguish them from imagination.

Comment: Your example sentence seems meaningless - I don't know what "adaptations language" is supposed to mean. I also don't think there's an exact word that describes the precise meaning you want - you'll just have to assemble a phrase (something like "theory of truth" is jargonny, but you're better off just saying what you mean rather than trying to find a jargon term).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Humans have a different **heuristic** to most other species...

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(psychology)):

> Heuristics is the process by which humans use mental short cuts to arrive at decisions. Heuristics are simple strategies that humans, animals,[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/199107/371882)[3](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22heuristic%20theory%20in%20contrast%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) organizations,[4](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nomothetic) and even machines[5] use to quickly form judgments, make decisions, and find solutions to complex problems. Often this involves focusing on the most relevant aspects of a problem or situation to formulate a solution.[6][7][8][9] While heuristic processes are used to find the answers and solutions that are most likely to work or be correct, they are not always right or the most accurate.[10]...

> Judgments and decisions based on heuristics are simply good enough to satisfy a pressing need in situations of uncertainty, where information is incomplete.

At
[What is a single word for the capability of a theory, for example, to generate further thought and theorizing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190361/what-is-a-single-word-for-the-capability-of-a-theory-for-example-to-generate-f) , I found the following commentary at [rhetorician's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/199107/371882):

> I only knew the computing usage [of "heuristic"] until I found *Educational: Of or relating to an educational method or resource that enables students or children to learn by making discoveries for themselves, rather than being directed* in OED yesterday. But today I just searched Google Books for "a heuristic theory" and found [A heuristic theory, in contrast to a nomological one, appeals to our knowing how to go about in the world.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22heuristic%20theory%20in%20contrast%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) Forcing me to look up **nomological** = [nomothetic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nomothetic) Of or relating to the study or discovery of general scientific laws. I'd have thought the implication is that *nomological/nomothetic* theories are the ones that lead to ***further*** theories, because they're based on ***general*** principles, not context-specific ones. –
> FumbleFingers
> Oct 1, 2014 at 17:49

Comment: The quotation from Wikipedia does not support the assertion that humans have different heuristics to most other species.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark No, but that's Ichthys King's baby to defend, not mine. The quote given does not _preclude_ different strategies being used by the different species, I think--correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Indeed the quotation doesn't preclude the assertion in the first statement of the answer. But nor does the quotation *All men are mortal.* (High Performance Mark, after Socrates). Neither your quotation nor mine support the assertion.

Comment: @High True, they don't--I'll give you that. But -- I can't remember who said this (I think it was in some essay by Bertrand Russel) and a quick google search didn't find it: "It is amazing how much of human speech can be explained without appealing to thought", leaving us to wonder (if we confine ourselves to science) whether humans really do use a different _anything_ than the other species to decide what's true. I, on the other hand, have a conviction (can't prove it, you know) that people _do_ think differently, but I don't even have any good scientific arguments for it..

Comment: @High You're not saying that my answer is completely orthogonal, are you? Because it could be, you know; it's just the first word that came to my mind (if you accept that I have one, of course!) and I've been wrong before, and probably will be after. "For I am a bear of very little brain.."

Comment: *You're not saying that my answer is completely orthogonal* No, I'm not, well, not deliberately, I don't know what you mean by *completely orthogonal*. But relax, no more from me on this.